# How to provide GDAL algorithms that require multiple layer input in the graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis-processing

Some GDAL algorithms such as gdalbuildvrt or gdalmerge require the selection of input layers.
How to make an entry in a graphical model from a list provided by the processing flow?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3, you can use the **Multiple input** parameter and select `Raster` as the *Data type*. You can then connect this parameter to a tool which requires multiple inputs:

[image: Multiple input model]

Running the model:

[image: Running model]

Comment: @FERRATON - Most welcome, glad it helped :)